# Post a notification within a NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, nsoperationqueue

I need you help with `NSNotificationCenter`. I have a class called `Sensor` and a class called `SensorManager`. I'd like to send notification from `Sensor` to `SensorManager`. In the `SensorManager` I write this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];
```

And, clearly, I have this function:

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{                
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}
```

In the Sensor class I have a function that starts the sensor:

```
-(void)workSensor{               
        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.05;

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error) {                
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self];

            NSLog(@"Udapte iphone acc data!");
        }];
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, `SensorManager` doesn't catch the notification. The strange thing (from my point of view) is that if I move the notification code outside the NSOperationQueue block, all works great (see the code below):

```
-(void)workSensor{    
            //now the notification is here. Outside the block.
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self];

            self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.05;

            NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
            [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error) {                


                NSLog(@"Udapte iphone acc data!");
            }];
        }

    }
```

How can I put the notification sender inside the `NSOperationQueue` block? Thank you!

Comment: Are you seeing the "Udapte iphone acc data" message when the app runs? I.e. is that handler called at all? Also, did you edit your notification key when posting the question? I.e., is it possible you mistyped the notification name in your actual code? (BTW, you can avoid that problem by not using separate string literals, but rather have a single global constant that you refer to both when posting as well as when handling the notification.)

Comment: Yes, I can see "Update iphone acc data" and no, unfortunately, there's no error in the name of notification... Thank you for helping me!

Comment: np. Bottom line, there's no problem posting notifications from operation queue, so it's got to be something else. If you still are having problems, create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch, some minimal example that reproduces the problem you describe. I cannot reproduce your problem (suggesting that the problem is elsewhere in your code), but if you give us verifiable example, then we can help you further.

Comment: @superpuccio...pls share ur updated answer here...

Answer (score 0):

Notifications should be posted on the main thread, so you should to something like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendNotification) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

which will call the function on the main thread. Then define the notification sending function:

```
- (void)sendNotification {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myEventName" object:self]; 
}
```

Comment: No, notifications don't have to be posted from main thread, though it's often useful to do so. BTW, in another discussion, the OP insists that he's tried dispatching the posting of the notification to the main thread, and that did not solve his issue. Bottom line, I don't believe that posting the notification from the main thread solves the OP's problem. Plus, if we wanted to do this notification on the main thread, using GCD is easier way to do that (e.g. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });`).